# Why does cakephp truncate a section of text in my mail?

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I am creating a html message with cakephp. Within this message there is a html table, with a really long amount of text in it.

When I echo to see what it looks like, the message looks perfect, but when I mail the message, the text within the html table truncates. I tried with and without smtp authentication with no change.
I store the message in a variable ($body) and then I send it like I normally would:

```
$this->Email->send($body)
```

Is there something that I need to do differently to prevent this?

Might this be a bug in cakephp? (I tested on 1.3.8 and 1.3.10)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the \n characters with `<br>` within a variable that I placed in the table which caused the line to be too long for email and was truncated there. I only needed to add `<br>` and not replace \n.